# Can't assign mass attributes to comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: answer. (Using Rails3)

I'm not sure why it's not allowing me to do so as I have my nested attributes accessible.

This is my answer model

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :question
    attr_accessible :anonymous, :answer, :commenter, :votes, :comments_attributes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

This is my comments model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer
  attr_accessible :anonymous, :comment, :writer, :votes
end
```

I'm failing at this form on the view

```
<%= form_for([@answer, @comment]) do |f| %>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :comment %>
        <%= f.text_area :comment, :cols => "50", :rows => "30"%>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit "Submit Comment" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

This is my function in my commentsController that is apparently causing the error

```
def create
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
    @comment = @answer.comments.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.save
        redirect_to question_path(@answer)
end
```

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? Look in your Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Your view code is not technically right. You need to use fields_for:

```
<%= form_for([@answer, @comment]) do |f| %>

    <p>
        <%= f.fields_for :comments do |u| %>
            <%= u.label :comment %>
            <%= u.text_area :comment, :cols => "50", :rows => "30"%>
        <% end %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit "Submit Comment" %>
    </p>
<%  end %>
```

you may also need to remove @comment from the form_For helper.  In fields_For, you might need to user :comment or possibly even @comment.

If you are using rails 4, then you will also have a problem with strong parameters: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: Why is that? also, that doesn't seem to solve the problem unfortunately